# How I can unit test componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) with jest?

Tags: react-native, testing, jestjs

How cand I unit test componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) with jest?

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.data === undefined || 
        nextProps.data.hasOwnProperty('error') || 
        nextProps.err !== undefined) {
        this.setState({
        messageError: "Something went wrong!"
        });
    }  else if ((nextProps.data).length) {
        this.setState({
            dataArray: nextProps.data
        });
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think here is the answer for you question https://medium.com/@pchomphoosang/react-js-how-to-do-unit-testing-on-componentdidmount-componentwillreceiveprops-866385c3e5dc

But I would recommend moving your code from componentWillReceiveProps to shouldComponentUpdate since CWRP is deprecated.

Comment: I'd add that state changes happened in `componentWillReceiveProps` we can test by checking `render()` outcomes - say by verifying if some element appeared or disappeared(because articles focuses on callback prop check only)

Comment: Thanks! I almost figured out how i can do it except how I can test  this.setState({
            dataArray: nextProps.data
        }); this branch?